# Как изменить папку views используя ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Я использую шаблоизатор ejs в своём проекте.
Меня в нём всё устранивает, но мне не нравится, что мой index.html файл лежит в папке views. Есть ли возможность изменить эту папку на свою ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. Если используете Express, то укажите в настройках:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/yourViewDirectory'));
```

Либо укажите путь при формировании рендера:

```
app.get('/your/path', function(req, res) {
  //viewname can include or omit the filename extension
res.render(__dirname + '/folder/with/views/viewname')); 
});
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло.